# Como puedo ver el contenido de una base de datos en el navegador?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una base de datos que fue creada con una versión de `SQL Server` vieja y estoy tratando de abrirla en una versión nueva. Me sale un mensaje que dice:

> "The database cannot be opened because it is versión 852. This server
>   supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported."

Me recomendaron que abra la base de datos en el navegador y copie todo a la versión nueva, pero no se como hacerlo. Si tienen una mejor solución déjenme saber.

Comment: No es al revés? Pareciera que la versión que quieres abrir es 852 (SQL Server 2016) en un servidor que soporta hasta la 782 (SQL Server 2014 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que dice el mensaje de error, lo que estas intentando hacer es abrir una base de datos de **SQL Server 2016** en un motor de **SQL Server 2014**.

Como la estructura nueva es muy diferente entre las dos versiones, lo que podrías hacer (siempre y cuando tengas acceso a la base de datos original) es **crear los scripts de la base de datos** de estructura (Tablas, Vistas, stored procedures, etc.) y su contenido (los datos) usando SQL Server Managment Studio (Click derecho sobre la base de datos >Tareas> Generar Scripts).

Con esos scripts crearías la base de datos completa en SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Podria ver la estructura de la base de datos desde SQl Server 2014 y luego pasarla a la versión nueva?

Comment: Si tenés SSMS no deberías tener inconveniente en ver la base y convertir los sripts...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una utilidad de administración web para la base de datos.
Puedes probar:
https://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Intenta abrirla con una herramienta de base de datos multiplataforma, solo necesitas las credenciales de logeo y ya, te recomiendo esta: http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/
En el link descargas la versión correspondiente a tu sistema operativo, la instalas y posterior te conectas con tus credenciales de la instancia de SQL.